# alineación automática de sub menus

Tags: css

Estoy tratado de hacer que un **submenu** varié su posición en función de si entra en la pantalla o no.

En el **Snippet** van a ver un menú similar al que quiero hacer y si se ponen en las oficinas de nueva york (y además la pantalla queda chica) el **sub menú** queda por fuera de la pantalla y me gustaría que se alinee para el otro lado, es posible?

```css
/* Menu Styles */

.third-level-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -150px;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
.third-level-menu > li {
  height: 30px;
  background: #999999;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
.second-level-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  
 
}
.second-level-menu > li {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background: #999999;
  
}
.second-level-menu > li:last-child {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
}

.second-level-menu > li:hover {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
.top-level-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.top-level-menu > li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #999999;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
.top-level-menu li:hover > ul {
  /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
  display: inline;
}
/* Menu Link Styles */

.top-level-menu a
/* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */

{
  font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.top-level-menu a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="top-level-menu">
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Offices</a>
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Chicago</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">New York</a>
        <ul class="third-level-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Information</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Book a Meeting</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Jobs</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Seattle</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Tambien pueden ver el codigo en el JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/cw8w6rwr/)

Comment: Andres, si la respuesta no cumple tus expectativas, comenta por favor para ver si se puede mejorar en algo. La idea en SO es que estas respuestas ayuden tanto al OP como a futuros visitantes. Quedo atento a tus comentarios!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que necesitas es que el menú se colapse cuando la pantalla llegue a cierto tamaño... Si es así, es posible que el siguiente ejemplo con `media-queries` te ayude a lograrlo.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);

body {
 background: #212121;
 font-size:22px;
 line-height: 32px;
 color: #ffffff;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 word-wrap:break-word !important;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }

h1 {
 font-size: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF;
} 

h3 {
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 34px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF;
}

h3 a {
 color: #FFF;
}

a {
 color: #FFF;
}

h1 {
 margin-top: 100px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:60px;
 line-height: 70px;
 font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
 }

#container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 890px;
}

p {
 text-align: center;
}

.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
 display: none;
}

/* Asignar un background-color al contenedor del nav. */
nav { 
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #254441;
}

#logo {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 30px;
 float: left;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height: 60px;
}

/* agregamos un clear después del container. */

nav:after {
 content:"";
 display:table;
 clear:both;
}

/* Removemos el padding, margin and "list-style" de la lista "ul",
 * y agregamos "position:reltive" */
nav ul {
 float: left;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 }
 
/* Posicionamos los items de navegación inline */
nav ul li {
 margin: 0px;
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 background-color: #254441;
 }

/* Damos estilos a los links */
nav a {
 display:block;
 padding:14px 20px; 
 color:#FFF;
 font-size:17px;
 text-decoration:none;
}


nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #000000; }

/* Cambiamos el color al hacer Hover */
nav a:hover { 
 background-color: #000000; 
}

/* Ocultamos los Dropdowns por defecto
 * y les da mos una posición absoluta */
nav ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 60px; 
}
 
/* Mostramos los Dropdowns al hacer Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:inherit;
}
 
/* Dropdown primer nivel */
nav ul ul li {
 width:170px;
 float:none;
 display:list-item;
 position: relative;
}

/* Segundo, tercero y otros niveles */
nav ul ul ul li {
 position: relative;
 top:-60px; 
 left:170px; 
}


li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }


/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (max-width : 768px) {

 #logo {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
 }

 nav {
  margin: 0;
 }

 /* Ocultamos los menu de navegación por defecto */
 .toggle + a,
 .menu {
  display: none;
 }

 /* Damos estilos a toggle */
 .toggle {
  display: block;
  background-color: #254441;
  padding:14px 20px; 
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:17px;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:none;
 }

 .toggle:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
 }

 /* Mostramos el Dropdown al hacer click en el padre */
 [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
  display: block;
 }

 /* Cambiamos el ancho de los items a 100% */
 nav ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  }

 nav ul ul .toggle,
 nav ul ul a {
  padding: 0 40px;
 }

 nav ul ul ul a {
  padding: 0 80px;
 }

 nav a:hover,
  nav ul ul ul a {
  background-color: #000000;
 }
  
 nav ul li ul li .toggle,
 nav ul ul a,
  nav ul ul ul a{
  padding:14px 20px; 
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:17px; 
 }
  
  
 nav ul li ul li .toggle,
 nav ul ul a {
  background-color: #212121; 
 }

 /* Ocultamos los menu de navegación por defecto */
 nav ul ul {
  float: none;
  position:static;
  color: #ffffff;
 }
  
 /* Ocultamos los menus al hacer hover */
 nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
 nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: none;
 }
  
 /* Dropdown primer nivel */
 nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
 }

 nav ul ul ul li {
  position: static; 

 }

}

@media all and (max-width : 330px) {

 nav ul li {
  display:block;
  width: 94%;
 }

}
```

```html
<nav>
        

        <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li>

                <!-- Drop Down primer nivel -->
                <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Offices</label>
                <a href="#">Offices</a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Chicago</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
                    <li>
                       
                    <!-- Drop Down segundo nivel -->        
                    <label for="drop-3" class="toggle">New York</label>
                    <a href="#">New York</a>         
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3"/>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Book a Meeting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


        <p> Acá iría el contenido </p>
        <p> Observa el comportamiento del snippet en pantalla completa y luego cambia el tamaño de la pantalla para que puedas ver el menú colapsable en acción </p>
```